# How to handle useState in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm a beginner in react..
I'm currently practicing by changing the code to FC.

In the process of manipulating the state in React, I put {value:"x"} using useState, but the value does not come out. Do you know where I am going wrong?

### class code

```js
class Square extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: null,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button
        className="square"
        onClick={() => this.setState({value: "X"})} 
      >
        {this.state.value}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

### FC code

```js
function Square (props){
 
    const [message , setMessage] = useState({value:null});

    console.log(message);
    return (
        <button className="square" onClick={()=> setMessage({value:"x"}) } > //Error
            {setMessage.value} //Error
        </button>
    )
}
```

Comment: You're not being consistent - either store an object as the state value, _or_ a string.

Comment: do `setMessage({value: "x"})` and `{message.value}`. And, It's not `FP`(functional programming) it' `FC`(function component)

Comment: Ah, now I've caught inconsistent text. Shame...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `message.value` instead of `setMessage.value`

```
function Square (props){
 
    const [message , setMessage] = useState({value:null});

    console.log(message);
    return (
        <button className="square" onClick={()=> setMessage({value:"x"})} >
            {message.value}
        </button>
    )
}
```

In this `useState`, `message` is state to use, `setMessage` is for updating states

```
const [message , setMessage] = useState({value:null});
```

P/s: You have a syntax problem at `onClick`. I modified it for you too

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing the two approaches, in the FC way, you should do `setMessage("X")` to store `"X"` as the value of `message`. To be consistent with your Class example, the FC should be like so:

```
function Square (props){
 
    const [message , setMessage] = useState(null); // <--Here

    console.log(message);
    return (
        <button className="square" onClick={() => setMessage("x")}>
            {message}
        </button>
    )
}
```

But if what you want is to save an object as the value of `message` then it should be like this:

```js
function Square (props){
 
    const [message , setMessage] = useState({value:null});

    console.log(message);
    return (
        <button className="square" onClick={() => setMessage({value:"x"})}>
            {message.value}
        </button>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setMessage()` expects an object {value: "string"}, you are just passing a string ("x").
Also, to render the message in your  component, you will have to access `message.value`.

```html
function Square (props){
    
    const [message , setMessage] = useState({value:null}); 

    console.log(message);
    return (
        <button className="square" onClick={()=> setMessage({value: "x"}) } > //Error
            {message.value} //Error
        </button> 
    )
}
```